# read ms word with python

Tags: python, ms-word

I'm trying to read ms word with StringIO. But somehow the output become strange string

```
from docx import Document
import StringIO
import cStringIO

files = "D:/Workspace/Python scripting/test.docx"


document = Document(files)

f = cStringIO.StringIO()
document.save(f)
contents = f.getvalue()
print contents
```

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Are you trying to read the file into `f`? If so, why won't `f=open(files).read()` work? Also, what do you mean by "the output become strange string"? What is the output and what did you expect?

Comment: i already try that and still show the same output. The output can't be copy here. The output i want is the string inside ms word. I only want to read whole ms word

Comment: sorry for my bad english. Your answer is working. Thanks

Comment: If it works, would you mind upvoting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.save(f)` saves the file to a string, formatted as a .docx file. You're then reading that string, which will do exactly the same thing as `f=open(files).read()`. If you want the text in the *document*, you should use python-docx's API for that. I haven't used it before, but the documentation is here:

https://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

It looks like you could use something like this:

```
paragraphs=document.paragraphs
```

This is the list of `Paragraph` objects in the document. You can get the tex of that paragraph like this:

```
text="\n".join([paragraph.text for paragraph in paragraphs])
```

`text` will then contain the text of the document.